# How send messages to various phone number with ";" for separate (java android)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

```
    private void sendSMS(){

    String phoneNo = number.getText().toString().trim();
    String SMS = message.getText().toString().trim();

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null,SMS,null,null);
        Toast.makeText(this,"SMS est envoyé",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Erreur",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Hello, I have this piece of code that works successfully! But I want now sent message to various numbers with separate ";".

For example, in the emulator I want enter in the numbers zone (1254;2058;153348) and the massage has to be sent to all the contacts I have enter.

Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: Is there a reason not to split the string by ';' and just call this function on each value?

Comment: I'm a beginner in mobile programming and I didn't understand this solution, do you have an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phoneNo.split(";")` will give you `String` array with multiple contacts. use `for` loop for sending to multiple users/numbers

```
private void sendSMS(){
    String phoneNo = number.getText().toString().trim();
    String SMS = message.getText().toString().trim();

    if(phoneNo.contains(";"){
        String[] phoneNumbers = phoneNo.split(";");
        for(String number : phoneNumbers) sendSmsTo(SMS, number);
    }
    else sendSmsTo(SMS, phoneNo);
}

private void sendSmsTo(String SMS, String phoneNo){
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null,SMS,null,null);
        Toast.makeText(this,"SMS est envoyé",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Erreur",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```